# How to receive OpsWorks deployment notifications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I would like to receive a notification via a SNS topic (or maybe a SQS queue) when a OpsWorks stack or app deployment is complete. The topic should include the stack ID, the deployment result (successful or unsuccessful), and perhaps the stack's public-facing DNS name. Surprisingly, this doesn't appear to be an off-the-shelf feature.

Possible implementations:

- My deployment app could poll the stack's deployment status and block until the deployment is complete, at which point the app would take the responsibility of retrieving the stack's details and passing that into SNS. This is simple and straightforward but rather inelegant.
- I could write a Chef deployment hook to invoke the AWS API in a `ruby_block`, and attach this hook to the OpsWorks `restart` event. This is nice and clean, and all of my stack information is already provided to the recipe, but it introduces additional complexity to the overall deployment system.

Any better options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we do ourselves right now to is to hook into the deployment hooks ([ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-hooks.html) ) and and use AWS instance roles to send out sns/ses messages. There isn't an easy off the shelf item for this.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know that my suspicions (and solutions) are on point. 

After discussing with my team, we're actually going for my first solution for now, because the deployment manager is designed to fill OpsWorks gaps without imposing specific app structure (or adding any custom recipes).

Comment: Deployment hooks do not work anymore for Chef 12 :/. I've been using this, but it doesn't completely fill my needs: https://github.com/zuazo/chef_handler_sns-cookbook